# R DiagrammeR package Mermaid text using actual calculation results

Tags: text, diagrammer

I would like to utilize the DiagrammeR package for a simple flow chart in my Rmarkdown. However, I couldn't figure out a way to use actual output from a data table into the text.  Suppose I have a simple query of a database with total records, patients count and date in year info for three different cohorts.
I wanted to create a diagram using Mermaid. The codes look at this.

```
Total = paste0('Records:',b1$records,' Patients:',b1$patients,' Year:',b1$year)
# (Records:1000 Patients:822 Year:5)
Sub1 = paste0('Records:',b2$records,' Patients:',b2$patients,' Year:',b2$year)
Sub2 = paste0('Records:',b3$records,' Patients:',b3$patients,' Year:',b3$year)

mermaid("
graph TB
  A[Total] --> B{Sub1} --> C{Sub2}
  ")
```

Instead of Printing out diagram with:  Records:1000 Patients:822 Year:5 in the A, it shows verbatim word "Total".

Any suggestion on how to do it correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are one step away from what you'd like to achieve. Please try this simple example below to see the logic:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
```

#### Stracture:

```
DiagrammeR(
  "
  graph TB
  
  A[Question] -->B[Answer]
  "
)
```

#### 1. Define answer node:

```
B <- paste0("There are ", nrow(iris), " records")
```

#### 2. Combine it with other components, using ; to separate statements:

```
results <- paste0("graph TB; A[How many rows does iris have?]-->", "B[", B, "]")
```

#### 3. Call 'results' in DiagrammeR:

```
DiagrammeR(diagram = results)
```

#### The final plot should refresh when your calculation updates.

[The plot that calls your calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNzBH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little correction from the last answer of Grasshopper_NZ

DiagrammeR::**mermaid**(diagram = results)